# Reversing a 64 bit Integer

Tags: java

Example: `00010111` -> `11101000`

```
public long reverse(long x) {
    long r = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (x > 0) {
        int bit = 0x0001 & x;
        r += bit << (63 - i);
        x >>= 1;
        i++;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Can someone review my code and provide any comments or suggest a better way of doing this?

Comment: Greetings, your question can be put out of hold if you update it with code that does not contain an infinite loop.

Comment: Hi, sorry about the bad code - I have updated the code to remove the infinite loop. Thanks!

Comment: It might be too early for me, but Eclispse still says that `int bit = 0x0001 & x;` needs a cast to `int`, so it still doesn't compile.

Comment: If you care about performance, you should consider one of the alternative approaches listed at http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code does not work, right?

What you have is an infinite loop, because `x >> 1;` does not do what you think it does.

There are a number of things wrong in here....

1. if the input long value is negative, you will never reverse it (it's < 0).
2. you should read up on the zero-shifting operator `>>>`
3. you will need to do all the 64 bits of shift otherwise the you will only reverse the set bits .... i.e. `0x00000000000001` should reverse to `0x8000000000000000` and not `0x00000000000001`

The code you probably want will look more like:

```
public long reverse(long x) {
    long r = 0;
    for (int i = 63; i >= 0; i--) {
        r |= ((x >>> i) & 0x1L) << (63 - i);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Of course, you could always do:

```
public long reverse(long x) {
    return Long.reverse(x);
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is infinite loop in the code - apologize for that. Thanks for your great answer though!